# Android scroll view / background image / Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview

I would like to create scroll view with background image size bigger than screen to do kind of "long scroll page" app. I am using following XML for layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <ScrollView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        p1:background="@drawable/wallpaper"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My wallpaper (background image size is 1920x820.

**Question :**
Why my background on running app is always adjusted to screen size if I use scroll view tag?

**What I want to achieve :**
Same effect like here :
http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/use_a_scrollview/

**Testing env**
Nexus 4 simulator

Comment: Try adding an ImageView inside your scrollView and set the image source for that image view to be your background image

Answer (score 1):

The scrollable content is whatever is inside your `ScrollView`. In this case, all you have to do is create a `ImageView` inside your `ScrollView` and set is `src` attribute to `@drawable/wallpaper`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <ScrollView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">

        <ImageView
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:src="@drawable/wallpaper"/>
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Ps: I'd also change "p1" to "android", as it's the commom way of naming and [avoid using px](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I tried this solution  ,now I am able to scroll but image is still compressed ( there is black stripe above and below image) so scrolling is not on image but on image+layout.  Should I set some width,heigh property for image to avoid this ?